# Is youtuber a halal profession?

Tags: halal-haram, profession

I know that, using youtube for spreading islam(e.g. explaining islamic topics properly) is halal and even encouraged by some. But can I take it as a profession? Note that I would upload halal content only but the videos would most probably not spread islam(I think). Let me explain in more details: I have some ideas which I want to implement. Can i showcase these ideas and upload them on youtube? My contents would be similar to Mark Rober or Colin Furze(ckeck the out on yt if don't know them yet). I would earn my money by google ads, taking sponsorship from various companies and maybe by selling some products of my own. Note that my goal would be to upload content that will get the most views (meaning I will try my best to get more views) while not doing anything that would go agianst the shareeah. I read a hadeeth once that told us to not be famous( I can't remember the exact hadeeth and I don't know if it is sahih or not) But by trying to get more views i am trying to be more famous which contradicts with the hadeeth. So, is this  profession( and goals) permissible for me?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is a website, a tool in it's essence. Depending on what type of content you publish, promote, and advertise on your channel will determine whether working on this YouTube channel is haram/halal.

In Islam, we have [5 categories of permissibility](https://thedeenshow.com/halal-mustahabb-mubah-makrooh-haram/):

1. Fard (Mandatory)
2. Mustahab (Encouraged, liked)
3. Mubah (Permissible, neither encouraged or discouraged)
4. Makruh (Discouraged, disliked)
5. Haram (Forbidden)

So depending on which category your content falls in will determine whether you should or should not work on this channel.

For example, if you genuinely plan, with sincere intentions, to make a dawah channel and teach Islam in a good manner, then many would view that as **Mustahab**. If you plan to make a sports review channel where you review sports games then that would be considered **Mubah**. If you plan to make your channel an avenue for gambling or erotica of any sort then that would considered **Haram**.

Check this out as well: [Is it Halal to Earn Money from YouTube Videos?](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/halal-and-haram/halal-earn-money-youtube-videos/)

Use the best of your rationality along with knowing the Islamic view of the content you want to work on, and make a thought-out decision.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's haram but its disliked in Islam community, its not sinful to be a youtuber even if you monetize videos. Even if you are preaching Islam but if you preach it and monetize it will be very disliked upon the community, any other video is normal.
Also I encourage you showcase items etc. You can be famous and that its only there because famous people deal with a lot of haters spammers and paparazzi
Also please don't monetize Islamic videos

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

No, no one use Islam for profit in our prophet era, nor should we. I personally hate it whenever I saw a few imams with their big cars arriving at a masjid or Islamic event for a profit. I could understand that they probably need money for a living (you too) but our prophet doesn't earn a single penny from preaching Islam, personally I think it will deteriorate people trust in our message, some of them will think that you do this for money (which it is) and bring bad images for Islam

there are many halal professions out there, the one recommended by our prophet is to trade/open a halal retail / halal store. Allah gave us endless ways to earn profit, then why should we sell our own religion?

Comment: the downvote coming from money digging imam, busted!